# How can I convert the division of two integer values to a decimal using T-SQL against a iSeries AS/400 Database?

Tags: t-sql, casting, ibm-midrange, calculated-columns

Assuming the following query:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    COUNT(1) AS NumRecords,
    SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQty
    SUM(Quantity)/COUNT(1) AS Avg
FROM        SOME_TABLE
GROUP BY    ID
```

Right now it returns:

```
ID    NumRecords    TotalQty    Avg
1     15            6           2
```

I want it to return a decimal value with a Scale of 2 for `Avg` (i.e. "2.5").

I've tried to `CAST` the calcluation as a DECIMAL, NUMERIC, FLOAT, and VARCHAR, but it always returns an INTEGER.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to cast the inputs to the calculation not the result. Also any reason you aren't using the `AVG` function?

```
AVG(CAST(Quantity as decimal(10,2)))
```

Comment: CAST(SUM(Quantity) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)/CAST(COUNT(1)  AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) results in 21 decimal places being returned

Comment: I need another CAST around the entire calculation. So, to specify a scale, you need it around both inputs and the entire calculation.

Comment: @Eric - You should only need to cast one input to `decimal` to avoid integer division that will make the return type more predictable.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution is via implicit Casting.  I found this to be much cleaner SQL as well.  The precision will be determined by the number of trailing zeros used when multiplying by 1.

```
AVG(Quantity * 1.00)   //x.xx
AVG(Quantity * 1.0000) //x.xxxx
```